# Topics generated when we do a foreign key join between two KTables in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

What all topics get generated when we do a foreign key join between two KTables in kafka streams? And What all data does they contain?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of intermediate topics which you can observe for Kafka Streams applications: `-repartition` and `-changelog`.

`-repartition` topics requires when your Kafka Streams application invokes a command changing the key.

`-changelog` topics represent a changelog state (when you create KTables) where each data record in the stream captures a state change of the table. Please, see [duality-of-streams-and-tables](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/concepts.html#duality-of-streams-and-tables) for more information.

Comment: Thanks kikulikov. When I do join I am also getting topics like **x-subscription-response-topic, x-subscription-registration-topic**. What data does it contain? Any idea? 

For me My issue was **x-subscription-response-topic** topic contains double the data than in **x-subscription-registration-topic**. Please let me know if you have any idea.